# Set innerHTML value to a div element from code behind using a string as the div ID

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using the below code in my `.aspx` page.

```html
<form runat="server">
  <div style="background:#ffffff;height:1150px;width:100%">
    <center>
      <table class="calendar-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="cell">
              <div class="cell-day">
                <asp:Label ID="label_day_11" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
              </div>
              <div id="event_11" runat="server">

              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <table>
    </center>
  </div>
</form>
```

In my original code I will have a total of 6 rows and 7 columns and the label rows and columns will go from `11` till `67` in the form of a matrix. Here I would like to set the value of `label_day_11` from code behind using C# and for that I am using the below code,

```
int i = 1; // 1 till 6 rows
int j = 1; // 1 till 7 columns
string dayId = "label_day_" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
Label day = FindControl(dayId) as Label;
day.Text = "Monday";
```

The above code works fine. But now I want to assign a `innerHTML` value to the `event_11` div element also. But I am not sure how to get that ID and how to set the innerHTML. Is there any way to access the `div` control using a string in C# and then set a innerHTML value to it? In case of a `asp:Label` I used the control value as `Label` but not sure how to get the control of a normal html div element.

I tried the below code but it does not work for me.

```
string eventId = "event_" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
Control div = FindControl(eventId);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
div.RenderControl(w);
```

I am not sure how to proceed using this. Any solutions?

Comment: I think you should search for id clientid asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should work if you cast it to `HtmlGenericControl`.

```
HtmlGenericControl div = FindControl(eventId) as HtmlGenericControl;
div.InnerHtml = "your inner html";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx